# how can I declared this as a string in bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

// I want to insert the $product with a value of i9-7820aa and I know bind_param may be one of four types  i - integer d - doubles - string b - BLOB
and i got this error mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

```
$product = 'i9-7820aa'; 
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['nickname']);
$show = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['show']);

$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO my (page) // insert in sql
        VALUES('$product')");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $product, $name, $show);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: what are you binding?

Comment: the $product @Akin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use placeholders when binding. Without them, you are not doing anything

Here, you are binding three variables. So you need to have three placeholders for each of them, then in the `bind_param` function, add the variables.

Have a look at this [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more information

```
$product = 'i9-7820aa'; 
$name = $_POST['nickname'];// you do not need to escape anything
$show = $_POST['show'];


    $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO my (page) // insert in sql
            VALUES(?,?,?)");//we add three placeholders
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $product, $name, $show);// s stands for string, i stands for int, 
        $stmt->execute(); // returns true/false
```

Comment: also @janejoe I do not think you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: It's working now @Akin. Thank you so much. Lesson learned small mistake, big reward. God bless. Cheers!

Comment: Why I don't need mysqli_real_escape_string? @MasivuyeCokile I used it in my html form?

Comment: Click on the green tick @janejoe. and you do not need to escape anything. Thats one of the perks of using prepared statements

Comment: Here you go @Akin. Oh ok so it is ok just to leave it? or I need to edit it like this $name = ($connect, $_POST['nickname']);

Comment: just leave it as `$_POST`. As long as it is prepared statements, you do not need to escape anything of your post data. Check out the link i added in the answer

Comment: My pleasure. and God bless you too. :)